# Is this function increasing/decreasing and convex/concave?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The function is:

$$y= 3x + \ln\left(\frac {3x - 4}{x - 1}\right)$$

After differentiating I got:

$$y' = 3 + \frac 1{3x^2 - 7x + 4}\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;  y''= - \frac {6x - 7}{(3x^2 - 7x + 4)^2}$$

If you can't find any critical points for $f'$ how do you determine where it is increasing/decreasing, and similarly for $y''$, where it is convex/concave?

Comment: Set $y'=0$ and note that you can multiply through by the denominator of that fraction. Hence you can find critical points.

Comment: Well if $y'=0$ has no solutions then $y'$ can only change sign at points of discontinuity.  To be clear, though, how do you define this for $1<x<\frac 43$?  Do you leave it undefined?

Comment: The first derivative has no solutions, so just look at whether it is positive or negative to see if it the original function is increasing or decreasing (just plug in any viable test point into $y'$). The second derivative does have a solution, so you would try test points on either side to see if $y''$ is positive or negative, and on which intervals.

Comment: Be careful here...the derivative can change sign without ever being $0$, as it is undefined at least at $1$ and $\frac 43$.  As I said in my earlier comment, the entire function is undefined between those values (unless you meant to take absolute value inside the log.

Comment: So the function is increasing in (-∞, 1) and (4/3, ∞)?

Comment: Correct, and undefined in the gap (unless you specify a definition).

Comment: Just to say: it would be simpler to write the function as $3x+\ln(3x-4)-\ln(x-1)$ BUT you have to be very careful with the signs.  That way of writing it only makes sense if $x>\frac 43$.  In the other region you have to write $3x+\ln(4-3x)-\ln(1-x)$

Comment: Note too:  as a curiosity:  the "inflection point" at $\frac 76$ has no meaning as it happens to fall in the undefined strip.  Thus the concavity has constant sign in each of the two regions...but in this case that sign is different in the two regions.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that x is not defined at $x=1$ and $x=\frac{4}{3}$.

Set $y'=0$

$3+\frac{1}{3x^2-7x+4}=0 \Rightarrow 3x^2-7x+4=-\frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow 3x^2-7x+\frac{13}{3}=0$

$(-7)^2-4*3*\frac{13}{3}=-3<0$, so it doesn't have a solution.

However, we were assuming $3x^2-7x+4 \neq 0$ before. Now consider the case that $3x^2-7x+4=0$, and we get $x=1$ or $x=\frac{4}{3}$. Neither of the two points fall in the range of x, so we don't have to consider these two cases.

We can see that $y'$ is always greater than $0$, which means y is monotonically increasing. And since it is monotonically increasing, it is neither convex nor concave.